# How to get active window handle in mac OS?

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

I want to get active window handle without X11.I like use Carbon for this project.

Comment: Isn't carbon obsolete?

Comment: it is correct but i can not use cocoa into c++?

Comment: Are you creating the window using X11? Since that's a remote window server, your app doesn't have a handle within its own process space. The window would be in X11.app.

Comment: no i can not use X11 for this project.

Comment: You might look into `ActiveNonFloatingWindow`… Google found it, when I searched for the old-school `FrontWindow` API, but according to various discussions it seems to have had issues. Are you developing for a legacy platform, or what? Why are you using Carbon?

Comment: i use carbon because i want to use c++.

Comment: Note that C++ may be used with Cocoa by using the Objective-C++ compiler.  While you can't make an Objective-C++ class use C++ features (e.g. it can't be templated) you can certainly have code from both languages in the same file.  You can also keep them as separate files and link them together, e.g. call a function from your C++ code from within an Objective-C method.